# angular: project failed to start after nodejs upgrade to 12.x

Tags: node.js, angular, upgrade

My Angular project failed to build and start after upgrading nodejs from 10.x to 12.x with the following message:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Missing binding C:\xxx\client\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-72\binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Node.js 12.x
Found bindings for the following environments:
- Windows 64-bit with Node.js 10.x
This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
```

I try the `npm rebuild node-sass`, but it still can't work. So what's the issue?

Comment: Use the supported version, which is 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try these following things:

1. Removing node_modules and then `npm i`
2. uninstalling node-sass and then re-installing it.

   `npm uninstall node-sass 
    npm i node-sass`